# Rspec/capybara - simulate switch from Online to offline within a test (webkit driver)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, ujs

I have a ruby on Rails 4 app.
A user loads a page (called deal_page) then he clicks on  a button which loads a Rails UJS modal message.

If he is online WHEN he clicks the button, I show a message using javascript offline status recognition (inside the Rails UJS ajax event).

```
on('ajax:error',function(event,xhr, status, error){
            var isOnLine = navigator.onLine;
            event.preventDefault();
            if (isOnLine) {
              //do stuff }
            else {
              // for disconnected users WHEN triggering call to server, invite to reconnect           
              var msg;
              msg = Messenger().post({
                message:            "You lost internet,You need to be connected"
              });
            }

          });
```

I want to test in rspec/capybara (I use webkit driver) that the right content ("You need to be connected. Please connect and try again") is displayed in that case in my feature test.

```
context "As signed-in visitor who is OFFLINE line when he clicks on the area triggering the modal" do 

it "displays the right message " do
        visit deal_page_path(deal)
        # HOW TO ASSERT THAT THE USER LOSES HIS INTERNET CONNECTION
        # USER GOES OFFLINE 
        first("a#button").click            
        within('ul.messenger') do           
          expect(page).to have_content('You lost internet,You need to be connected')
        end
      end

  end
```

The complexity is that I can't disconnect him from the beginning of the test as he needs to be connected to load the page visit deal_page_path(deal) but then I want to simulate that he loses the internet connection.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're just checking `window.naviagtor.onLine` to determine whether or not it is on/offline (not depending on any events or anything) and because you're using `capybara-webkit` (won't work in selenium since FF won't let you overwrite navigator, not sure about poltergeist) you can just overwrite `window.navigator`  with the result you want to get. You'll also need to generate an error response for your ajax request, which you can do with puffing-billy

```
page.execute_script "window.navigator = { onLine: false }"
```

Comment: smart , so you advice splitting this into 2 tests: 1/ really test that if user goes offline, I get window.navigator = { onLine: false }, 2/ if window.navigator = { onLine: false } test that the correct modal and message gets displayed. I thought I could do both at the same time in my feature test but it's a valid suggestion. but then my question is in what kind of test (controller? feature ?....) and how could I test number 1/ ?

Comment: @Mathieu you can't really test #1 - there's no way to actually toggle to offline mid test (that I know of anyway).

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm a rookie but trying to apply things, TDD and all right so I was not sure.

Comment: will award the bounty in 12 hours, not allowed to do before by SO.:)